# MySQL: lists the tables that have an attribute which has "address" as a substring

Tags: mysql, database, attributes, substring

Give you a database with several tables, each tables have many attribute, some attribute may have "address" as a substring.

For example, there is a table Friends with two attribute oldAddress and newAddress.

So write a query that return the table "friends" and other tables that exist such attributes that the **address** is a substring of attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the columns using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view.  I think this does what you want:

```
select c.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where lower(column_name) like '%address%';
```

Comment: thanks~~~ It works well, by the way, what does lower method means?

Comment: It puts the string in lower case -- just a precaution for the matching of the names.